# Add margin to inline-block element independently

Tags: html, css

I want to apply an amount of space before an element in an unordered list. Here is the URL:http://hottdoggfilms.com. I try to centralize the dog's picture with logo in between the other list elements. But there is uneven space between the elements "Recent Work" and "About Us". My markup is:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <h1><a class="brand" id="cf" href="#"><img class="bottom"  src="hottdogg.png" data-min-width-481="hottdogg.png" alt="Tipit"><img class="top"  src="hottdogg.png" data-min-width-481="hottdoggHover.png" alt="Tipit"></a></h1>
            <nav class="nav-collapse collapse" role="navigation">
                <h2 class="visuallyhidden">Navigation</h2>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a  href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#recent-work">Recent work</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li style="margin-left:20px"><a  href="#about-us">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="#contact-us">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#navbar .nav {
   font-size: 0;
   text-align: center;
   white-space: nowrap;
   float: none;
   margin: 0;
}
#navbar .nav li {
   display: inline-block;
   float: none;
}
#navbar .nav a {
   margin-bottom: 0;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 37px;
   height: 37px;
   padding-left: 1.4em;
   padding-right: 1.4em;
}
#navbar .divider {
   width: 186px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, the nav is quite confusing, with the divider and all.
Why not to go for a simpler solution?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IeLCf

```
nav {
  margin:0 auto;
  border:1px dashed black;
  text-align:center;
}
nav a {
  position:relative;
  top:-100px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:left;


}

<nav>
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">LOOOOOOONG</a>
  <img src="http://hottdoggfilms.com/hottdoggHover.png" alt="" />
  <a href="">shrt</a>
  <a href="">LOOONG</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add width to `#about-us'` element 100px and lower the width of the `.divider` element to `145px`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer, having the image as part of your navigation is a better solution.

However, if you want to keep what you have now, you can use the :nth-child selector.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

in your case:

```
.nav > li:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: 60px; //as much as you need
}

//and for when the menu collapses
.nav > li:nth-child(3).small-screen {
    margin-left: 0; //or whatever the default is
 }
```

Comment: Does not serve my purpose. There is unwanted space between "Recent Work" and divider